# Subract values of 2 arrays and get a new array with subtracted values

Tags: ruby

Basically, I want to do this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].some_method([1,5,8,7,8])
=> [0,-3,-5,-3,-3]
```

What is the best way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[1,2,3,4,5].zip([1,5,8,7,8]).map { |a, b| a - b }
```

Comment: The other answers treat the zipped elements as arrays.  You're saying Ruby will convert them automatically to an arg list like this?

Comment: +1. Since this is kinda common I actually proposed the addition of a Haskell like `zip_with` method to Ruby. You can read the ongoing discussion here if you are interested: http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4539

Comment: @cHao: Yes it will. The concept is known as destructuring binding in some other languages.

Comment: Right, it's a destructuring assignment. You can get even more clever, you can `yield 1, [2, 3]` to the block `{ |a, (b, c)| . . . }`.

Comment: @digitalross...neat..but will this be an overhead because we are iterating through the arrays 2 times first for zip function and then for map function? (a `map_with_index` function would have been good here)

Comment: Typically, Ruby code runs fast when the built-in (i.e., coded in C) ops are used. This solution is almost exclusively built-in, so it should win there. Additionally, this code is 100% functional and all data is 100% immutable. So, I would say there are many justifications for doing it this way, and of course it's concise and easy-to-read. The machines are so insanely fast these days I usually go for code purity first. Plus, it makes no sense to optimize anything until it has been shown to be the bottleneck of a real system.

Answer (score 2):

```
p [1,2,3,4,5].zip([1,5,8,7,8]).map{|el| el.first-el.last}
#=> [0, -3, -5, -3, -3]
```

.zip combines both arrays like [[1, 1], [2, 5], [3, 8], [4, 7], [5, 8]]. With .map there isnt much work left for the block - just subtract the 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

```
[1,2,3,4,5].zip([1,5,8,7,8]).map{|x|x[0]-x[-1]}
```

or the usual array iteration

```
0.upto(a.size-1).map{|x| a[x]-b[x] }
```